# Using CSS, how do you add a rounded grey background to an element when the user hovers over it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a grey, rounded background to an  element when the user hovers over it. Ideally like the example. Before: [image: before hover image]

after: [image: after hover image]

```css
/* this is my current code (css) */
a:hover {
background-color: gray;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://somerandomlinks.com">Some Random link...</a>
<!--example link only -->
```

Instead, it turns into a weird oval-shaped thing.
 ***Note:*** I'm using a stack overflow button as an example. Sorry for the blurry image.

Comment: It's just filling the size of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `border-radius: 50px;` and `padding:10px;` instead of `border-radius: 50%;`

```css
a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<a href="http://somerandomlinks.com">Some Random link...</a>
<!--example link only -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You were actually really close, I just did a simple edit.

The CSS property `border-radius` basically counds your corners, and the higher the value, the more sharp of a rounding will occur. *50%* is actually a lot, so that's why it takes that long oval shape that you are mentioning.

Refer to this example:

```css
/* this is my current code (css) */
a:hover {
background-color: #eff0f1;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://somerandomlinks.com">Some Random link...</a>
<!--example link only -->
```

Example with more oval shape:

```css
/* this is my current code (css) */
a{
    padding: 10px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #eff0f1;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://somerandomlinks.com">Some Random link...</a>
    <!--example link only -->
```

Alternatively, if you want a background that exceeds that of the link text, you could construct a div that has a default property of `background-color: transparent;` and then upon hover, you remove that CSS property again, and add your desired `background-color` and `border-radius` with the values to your liking.

Example:

```css
/* this is my current code (css) */
.link-background {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.link-background{
  padding: 0.8%;
  width: 22%;
}

.link-background:hover{
  background-color: #eff0f1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="link-background">
<a href="http://somerandomlinks.com">Some Random link...</a>
<!--example link only -->
</div>
```

Comment: Last example: Probabaly better just to `display: inline-block` or `display: block` the `<a>` than add a containing element

Comment: Wouldn't that amount to the same solution as the first example @Scoots ? In my last example, I wanted a background that exceeded that of the link text, while still keeping a *"nice"* padding to create the desired effect OP was looking for. Again, I'm not really a CSS wizard, but I figured this would be a decent push in the right direction.

Comment: @Martin I'll probably combine your answer (transparency) with Vikas Jadhav answer (Vikas Jadhav answer looks more like the picture

Comment: Fair, I wasn't sure if you wanted an "animation-like" effect, i.e. adding the padding on the initial hover or not, as it will make the link bounce.

Comment: @Martin The big reason to avoid it is you now have a hover event to indicate a click, however not all areas that trigger the hover event are clickable. This is frustrating for end users. It gets even worse if space is limited and the link wraps onto another line.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the right direction but you just need to fill the space around your text with some padding to make it look more appropriate.

```
a:hover {
background-color: gray;
border-radius: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Link: https://codepen.io/Harsh89/pen/RYeWvX

Answer (score 0):

you must be looking for something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-default">example</a>
```

style:

```
<style>
.btn-default{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none; z-index: 1;
}

.btn-default:hover{
    background: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.btn-default::before{
    content: "";
    background:#666666;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; top:0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0);
    -moz-transform:scale(0);
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}

.btn-default:hover::before{
    transform: scale(1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Consider making snippets to present visual examples. Your code seems to be not working, when I put it into a snippet.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this editor. but here you go:

https://codepen.io/neel555nc/pen/EdmMyx

can you show me where its not working?